# Angle between $\left(\vec{u} + \vec{v}\right)$ and $\left(\vec{u} - \vec{v}\right)$

Tags: vectors

Given that the vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are not null, can we state that the angle between $\left(\vec{u} + \vec{v}\right)$ and $\left(\vec{u} - \vec{v}\right)$ is $\pi/2$?

If so, how can one prove it?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not. The sum and the difference are the two diagonals in the parallelogram formed by the two vectors. Those do not have to be perpendicular. You can take the vector/scalar product and see when they are null.

Comment: The angle between this vectors is $\theta\in[0,\pi]$, where $\cos\theta = \frac{<u+v,u-v>}{\|u+v\| \|u-v\|}$. $< >$ is the scalar product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Given any vectors $\vec a,\vec b$, the angle $\theta$ between them can be defined as:
$$\cos\theta=\frac{\vec a\cdot\vec b}{|\vec a||\vec b|}$$

So in this context,

$$0=\cos\frac{\pi}2=\frac{(\vec u+\vec v)\cdot(\vec u-\vec v)}{|\vec u+\vec v||\vec u-\vec v|}$$
$$\iff(\vec u+\vec v)\cdot(\vec u-\vec v)=0$$
$$\iff\vec u^2-\vec v^2=0$$

which is not always true.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is true if and only if $\;\lVert \vec u+\vec v\rVert=\lVert \vec u-\vec v\rVert$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ be any two vectors that are neither equal
nor exactly opposite one another.
Let $\vec u = \frac12(\vec a + \vec b)$ and let
$\vec v = \frac12(\vec a - \vec b)$.
Then neither $\vec u$ nor $\vec v$ is null,
while at the same time
$\vec u + \vec v = \vec a$ and $\vec u - \vec v =\vec b$.

In other words, unless you can give us some additional restrictions
on $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ other than "not null", the vectors
$\vec u + \vec v$ and $\vec u - \vec v$ could be
*just about any two vectors in the vector space,*
with only the restrictions that they can not be exactly equal
nor can one simply be the negation of the other.
The angle between them could be $0$, $\pi$, or anything in between.